Does PutACLAsync make a copy of an object?
When calling AmazonS3Client.PutACLAsync() does this update my existing object or does it make a copy of it with new ACLs?

The PutACLAsync() method is used to set the ACL for an existing S3 object. It does not create a new object; instead, it modifies the ACL associated with the specified object.

Thanks for the response @smac2020. I asked because I also wanted to update object metadata but that seems to make a copy of the object. I was wondering if ACL update was doing the same.
